# How to configure a project to use Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I'm trying to set up '[PartKeepr](http://partkeeper.org)', but keep getting the error at the prerequisites:

> Doctrine needs to be installed and in the PHP include_path

I 'installed' Doctrine through composer, following the instructions at
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/configuration.html, but I don't know where to include `require_once "vendor/autoload.php";`.

I tried adding several directories in my 'php.ini' file to the 'include_path', but without success.

Folder structure:

[image]

'vendor' folder contains all files created by 'composer', so I have to include 'vendor/autoload.php' somewhere.

So my question: where do I include `require_once "vendor/autoload.php";` and do I have to add anything to my 'include_path' in php.ini?